# W3C Validation Error: document type does not allow "strong"

Tags: w3c-validation

I want to append some text in the HTML document using jQuery. The font weight of the appended text should be **BOLD**. For that I do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.append-here').append('<strong>'+$.cookie('XYZ')+'</strong>'));
</script>
```

It works like this but this gives me W3C error: **document type does not allow element "strong" here**.

Now, if I write `strong` tag outside script tag, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you validate the original HTML or the HTML after JS ran? Where do you append this `strong` element to?

Comment: @unor I am trying to validate it through url. Here is the link http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ps-friend.com%2Fbrush%2Fpage%2F1%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Comment: Then you may add the solution as an answer. And note that you shouldn’t use the `strong` element simply because you want something to be bold; the `strong` element has a [defined meaning](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) (only use it if your case matches the spec).